# API Access with Contact Manager Edition

Tags: api, appexchange, editions

I'm doing some research for a customer and I'm a bit confused on whether it is possible to add contacts/leads to SalesForce if the user is on Contact Manager Edition.

From what I'm reading, API access is only available to Enterprise/Unlimited (and sometimes Professional)

I found one app, however, that claims that they can add contacts/leads if you have Contact Manager edition:

https://fullcontact.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/169820-card-reader-frequently-asked-questions-faqs

At first I thought that perhaps they do it via some back-door with their AppExchange app.  But their AppExchange App requires Group Edition+.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B3F7rEAF

Is there some magic I don't know about, or is their Knowledge Base stating something impossible?